# What is required to work PHP post form method?

Tags: php, html

I am new to php so help me to make it work. Required action completed by opening the ready.php file but entered form data is not displaying in ready.php file.

i AM USING THIS CODE in index.php for form.

```
<form method="post" action="ready.php">
<div class="enter-name">
    <input class="animated pulse infinite" type="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="n" placeholder=" Enter Your Name Here">
    <button class="btn animated shake infinite" type="submit"><span></span> Go</button>
</div>
```

code for ready.php

```
<figure>
<h1 class="naming"></h1>
<h1 class="naming"></h1>
<h1 class="naming"></h1>
<h1 class="naming"></h1>
<h1 class="naming"></h1>
```

or

```
<div class="busi"><br><img src="4.png" height="35px" width="35px"/>
```

I am not getting what the problem with that.

Comment: No but your ready.php needs to look for the post values and populate the fields. You don't get it for free. Google "php form post" and you should get a wealth of information. This is not a tutorial site and you need to put some leg work in on learning the concepts first. Then if you have specific questions about bugs you encounter (not teach me basic php/client-server development) then come back with those specific questions.

Comment: You haven't even explained what do you want do to with the data in ready.php. In theory you do not need a database connection, although you will probably want one... I am guessing you want to store a list of names. I have no idea what the image has to do with anything. Besides that, I would suggest to pick some examples online... notice that the question has nothing of php or mysql, it appears you haven't tried yet. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Form is just to enter the name which will display in ready.php file.  the error there is that name value come blank in ready.php                                                      is there any requirement to change the code in ready.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve my above problem by applying this code

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['n'];?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a database connection for this, but you do need to be running/have access to some sort of server with php functionality (apache is a good choice).

Regarding the code, I'm no expert, but you could try adding the "name" attribute, because that's what the php script is going to look for. I added it below (name = "name"). You also need to change the input type to text (type="text"):

```
<input class="animated pulse infinite" type="text" name="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="n" placeholder=" Enter Your Name Here">
```

in your php script, you can find the name variable from the textbox by using this code:

```
$myName = $_POST['name'];
```

The name will be inside the variable $myName.

Good luck!

Comment: its not working. my form area to fill name remove only go button is there.

Comment: The way I learned PHP was through basic examples on websites. It looks like you're trying to do several different, complicated things in your code. You should try a simple example to get the PHP working, and then add all the cool features on top of it. A really, really simple example can be found on (https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_forms.asp) at the top of the page. Try it out and see if it works for you!

Comment: Another thing to consider is: where is your php script? Is it in the same directory as your html file? If you want your html file to communicate with the php script, the html file needs to know where the php script is. You can set the path inside the "action" tag like this: action="/path/to/file/ready.php"

Comment: both the file in the same folder and index file directed another file to open. but the only problem is that my form data from index.php file to ready.php not directed.